# Why is matrix calculus still taught / useful?

Tags: matrices, soft-question, matrix-calculus, tensors

Wikipedia has a huge page on [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus), and there exist resources such as the [The matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), which contain *huge sets of rules*  on how to take derivatives $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ of various combinations of $y, x$ as scalars, vectors, and matrices.

However, can't *all the rules* be mechanically derived by following einstein tensor notation? Einstein tensor notation has the advantages of:

1. Not needing to remember lists of rules, many complex and error-prone
2. Generalizing to handle arbitrary cases of mixtures of matrices, vectors, and scalars
3. Often smaller proofs?

So I really don't understand why matrix calculus is even taught in the first place. Can someone please help me see what I am missing?

EDIT: as an example of where I feel einstein tensor notation shines, say we wish to calculuate $\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}$, where $X: \mathbb R^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is a matrix function. Such a calculation simply cannot be done with matrix calculus, since the resulting object will have four indices, while matrix calculus can only "give outputs" in terms of scalars, vectors and matrices. This is crazy limiting, since the theory doesn't even provide a *complete* solution to differentiating matrices!

We can of course work through the $(\epsilon-\delta)$ formalism to arrive at the answer. However, tensor notation makes this clear and easy (follow the rules of single-variable calculus!) since we are forced to talk  about tensors "element-wise":

$$
\frac{ \partial X}{\partial Y} = \partial_{Y^{ij}} X^{ab}
$$

which now has four indeces$(i, j, a, b)$. If we now know that $Y = X$ for example, we can plug this information in:

$$
\frac{ \partial X}{\partial Y} = \partial_{Y^{ij}} X^{ab} = \partial_{X^{ij}} X_{ab} = \text{$X^{ij}$ is independent from $X^{ab}$} = \delta_i^a \delta_j^b
$$

Comment: This may be better-suited to matheducators.se.

Comment: I don't see why choosing a different notation would make the proofs any easier. The results are mechanical in either way and I don't really see a need to differentiate between scalar/vector/matrix when just talking about, say, general maps $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. As for why matrix calculus is taught, see the applications section. Maybe I am missing something, but I don't understand why using a different notation would change the substance of the subject.

Comment: I assume $X$ is to be understood as a function that maps matrices (where $Y$ lives) to matrices (where the 'matrix' $X$ lives). The process to calculate a derivative for maps like this is well established, and assuming the derivative exists, it is perfectly well defined. It extends the notion of derivative for real functionals and can be calculated by taking the limit quotient with small matrices (using norms for computing sizes), or it can be found via, say, best linear approximations.

Comment: Yes, I know the process (as taught in real analysis). But what's the use of the rules of entire treatises such as the "Matrix cookbook" if Einstein notation is more convenient and complete?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri yes, your understand is correct of what $X$ is, let me fix the text :) Thanks for the correction

Comment: If you think of them less as rules and more as formulas, then perhaps this would help? Because matrices have structure, we can sometimes leverage that structure in making sense of or in simplifying calculations that could yes otherwise be carried on through basic definitions.

Comment: if you are going to take a coordinate intensive view, OP said  *as an example... say we wish to calculuate $\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}$, where $X: \mathbb R^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is a matrix function. Such a calculation simply cannot be done with matrix calculus, since the resulting object will have four indices, while matrix calculus can only "give outputs" in terms of scalars, vectors and matrices.*  But this isn't really true.  It's extremely common to use the vec operator and Kronecker product to work around these issues.

Comment: @user8675309 can you provide an example of how to use these operators in this case? I haven't seen much use of these, and I'd be glad to learn!

Comment: for starters there's a Dover book "Kronecker Products and Matrix Calculus with Applications" by Graham. It's a handbook, not theory.  But it *is* a Dover.